# Using a case expression on a column of type number to output it as string

Tags: sql, oracle

IN Oracle DB, how can I use a case expression on a column of type number to output it as string if the column value equal a certain number?

For example:

```
SELECT name,
       address
       CASE
          WHEN my_num = 5 THEN 'some_string_one'
          WHEN my_num = 10 THEN 'some_string_two'
          WHEN my_num = 20 THEN 'some_string_three'
          ELSE my_num
       END AS my_num_in_string
FROM foo
```

Problem with what I have above is that I get the error

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got NUMBER

I need a column where the numerical values are mapped to a string. Is that possible?

Comment: Note that your attempt shows a `case` ***expression***. `case` ***statements*** exist too, but only in PL/SQL, not in SQL. I edited your post to reflect that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `case` *expression*'s different return values must have compatible data types.

```
SELECT name,
       address
       CASE
          WHEN my_num = 5 THEN 'some_string_one'
          WHEN my_num = 10 THEN 'some_string_two'
          WHEN my_num = 20 THEN 'some_string_three'
          ELSE to_char(my_num)
       END AS my_num_in_string
FROM foo
```

Comment: I tried `ELSE TO_CHAR(my_num)` and `cast(my_num as varchar2(30))` but I don't understand why this works. Wouldn't this only convert columns where my_num isn't 5,10 or 20?

Comment: The previous return values are already character strings. Only the ELSE needs to be converted.

Comment: I see I was under the assumption that the previous matches were failing too. Makes sense. Thank you!!!

Comment: but the column only has the distinct values of 5,10 or 20. Nothing else. So why would ELSE throw an error as if there exists a number like 111 that should be matched in the ELSE and needs to be converted to a string?

Comment: @DanteGreyson - because that's a syntax error, checked **before** seeing the data. The parser doesn't know that the only values will be 5, 10, 20. If you know that those are the only possible values, why do you have `else my_num` and not `else null`? **You** know that the `else` branch will never be reached; the parser doesn't. (With that said: `else null` is the default anyway, so you can leave it out altogether!)

Comment: The error is raised by the SQL compiler, i.e. before any table data has been read.

Comment: @jarlh - just wondering, why `cast` and not simply `to_char()`?

Comment: @mathguy, because I don't know Oracle... I'll edit!

Comment: @mathguy Okay that makes so much sense now, I was not fully understanding how case statement works. If I leave out the else I don't even get the error. Thank you for the insight.